# How add 1 in math expression inside TikZ \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

How can the loop in the following be modified so that the printed subscript is not the current value of `\n` but rather the incremented value `\n` + 1 (as in integer, not floating point)?

In other words, the three pictures drawn should have the nodes labeled as $\rho_2$, $\rho_3$, $\rho_4$ rather than $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$, $\rho_3$.

I do *not* want to change the `\draw (0,0) circle(\n)` part (which in practice will be a much more complicated expression involving `\n`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle(\n) node {$\rho_{\n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic way using e-TeX's `\numexpr` (all current engines have this e-TeX extension):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,3} {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle(\n) node {$\rho_{\the\numexpr \n + 1\relax}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the `\relax` may be omitted here, because the closing brace `}` would terminate the numeric expression.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `evaluate` in the `\foreach` loop:

```
\foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n+1)] in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle(\n) node {$\rho_{\m}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

This creates a new variable `\m` that has the value `\n+1`. You need `int` in the expression because `evaluate` will assume you want a float otherwise and produce `2.0`, `3.0`, etc. You can similarly give `\m` the value of any function of `\n`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\inteval` from the package `xfp`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\incr}{O{1}m}{\inteval{#1+#2}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle(\n) node {$\rho_{\incr{\n}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

You can also do `\incr[2]{\n}` to increment by 2 and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

egreg's answer is very likely more efficient, but here's mine anyway. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\n-1}
\pgfmathprintnumberto{\m}{\p}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle(\n) node {$\rho_{\p}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

`\pgfmathsetmacro` substracts 1 to `\n` but the result is a float, so `\pgfmathprintnumberto` rounds it to an integer value and stores it in `\p`.

or another solution using Lua, just for fun (and also easy to expand):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}

\directlua{
  function addone(x)
    tex.print(x+1)
  end
}
\newcommand{\addone}[1]{\directlua{addone(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle(\n) node {$\rho_{\addone{\n}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, for TikZ's `foreach` only: let `\n` runs from 2 to 4 instead of from 1 to 3, so TikZ accepts `\n` as the content of the `node`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {2,...,4}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(\n-1) node[magenta]{$\rho_{\n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not *that* dense! Alas, in the "real-world" use I want to make of this, changing the range from 2 to 4 instead of from 1 to 3 does not take care of the matter: whatever the value of `\n` fed into the function inside the `tikzpicture` environment, I still need the subscript printed to be one more that the value of `\n`

Comment: you are right! my solution is just for this particular situation. In my opinion, the simplest and general solution is of Miyase https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646917/140722